# print data from two tables and get all projects that relate to one customer

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, crystal-reports

[tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XNhXZ.png)I have three  tables in Sql 
table 1 : Customers
table 2 : Projects
table 3 : Project_cust "relate between projects and customers "

I want to print data from two tables "Customers" & "Project_cust " where customer id in table 2 equals id in table 1 and get all projects that relate to that customer in one row 
like that :
Customer 1 | project 1| project 2 | ..etc

I am using Asp.net and Crystal Report in C#

Comment: have you linked tables?

Comment: yes , the third table "Project_cust " is the link table 
it have customer_id and Project_id
@Siva

Comment: you need to link 3 tables and then take the required fields from 3 tables then display in crytal reports

Comment: I did that :
"select  it.name,v.project_name ,it.ssi,it.address , it.phone,SUM(money) as total  from customers it  join project_cust v on it.id = v.customer_id  where it.del = 'False' and v.del = 'False'  group by it.name,it.ssi,it.phone,it.address,v.project_name "
but the result was in more than one row for one customer
i want all projects in one row for one customer 
@Siva

Comment: can you show the preview couldn't understand more than one row part?

Comment: I added a screen shot of the sql query above in the main Question @Siva

Comment: There are 4 names so you get 4 rows it is the database behaviour if your query returns one row it will return one if not it will return as many rows as database returns

Comment: If you want in one row then how do you need in one row?

Comment: I mean that for customer 1 return 1 row   with his all projects 
don't repeat customer name  for every project 
for Example : if customer 1 has 5 projects , i want one row with that  customer name and his 5 projects 
not 5 rows 
@Siva